# PHP Profile Picture Upload And Insert Location In Database Using Jquery And Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i wan't to create facebook like profile picture upload system i need it for project **it is possible to call php file with jquery ajax and move uploaded file into selected folder and insert picture location into database and output data to selected div ?**
Any kind of help will be appreciated thanks.

below is my code

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Member Area
</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#register").click( function() {
        $.post( $("#form").attr("action"), $("#form :input").serializeArray(), function(info) { $("#results").empty(); $("#results").html(info)} );
    });
    $("#form").submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="php_file.php" method="POST">
<br /><input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
<button name="submit" id="register">Register</button>
</form>

<div id="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

php_file.php

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = "user1";
    include_once("db.php");
        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tmp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        if($file)
        {
            $location = "avatars/$file";
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,$location);
            $query = "UPDATE users SET image_location ='".$location."' WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
            $query2 = "SELECT image_location FROM users WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
            $image_location = $row['image_location']; 
            echo "<img src='".$image_location."' height='200px' width='200px'>";
        }
        else
        {
            $errors = "<div id='errors'>You must choose image with jpg , jpeg , png , gif this field cannot empty.</div>";
        }
if(isset($errors)) { echo $errors; }
?>
```

Comment: many questions in one... what have you tried already?

Comment: i call php file using jquery ajax call perfectly but it can't send file input to php file

Comment: Please show code.... what you've attempted.... where it is failing... etc. You should put as much effort into a question as you are asking others to put into any answers.

Comment: now i update my post with code

Comment: Output what? The image, the path to it, size, etc? And also you need to check for extensions for that error

Comment: i wan't to output image when everything successfull this script is only for question i know that i need to check for extensions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uploading files asynchronously in a cross-browser way isn't easy. I suggest you use an existing jquery plugin like the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload). It will make things much easier for you.

Also, functions like [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) are deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension instead if possible.

Comment: General information and fails to answer any part of the question.

Comment: @Scott This question was asked almost an hour ago and noone even made an attempt to provide an answer. Do you think it will be better to leave it like that? At least I gave the OP something to look into.

Comment: @Nikos thanks for your effort I'm already using this plugin I want to make this without any plugin is there any other way available ?

Comment: @anushn You could use the fallback method this plugin uses to make the solution cross-browser. Use an iframe element and post the content of your form through that.

Comment: @Nikos thanks for your reply i am not professional is there tutorial available how to use iframe on this particular topic